# Embedded profiler for PHP

Tags: apache2, php, profiling, xhprof

I want to profile some [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) code, function by function, so I need a profiler that can check block of code. I found [XHProf](https://github.com/facebook/xhprof), and I was able to install it on [MAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP) following the guide *[Profiling with XHProf](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2009/12/01/profiling-with-xhprof/)*.

The problem is that I am working on a test server remotely, which I don't have the rights to, and I don't really want to tweak...

Is there a code solution for profiling?

Must I put my hands on the server's configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) profiler with [KCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html). Have a look at the blog post *[Profiling a PHP Application](http://erichogue.ca/2011/03/linux/profiling-a-php-application/)*.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. However, someone might install the xhprof for me.
I found an usage example [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110514095512/http://mirror.facebook.net/facebook/xhprof/doc.html#using_extension)